# test class of account entitlement passed but zero coverage

Tags: account, entitlements

```
`public class AccountEntitlementTriggerHandler {

//VARIABLES
Map<Id,Entitlement> entitlementMap {get;set;}
List<Entitlement> entList {get;set;}


public void OnAfterUpdate(Map<Id,Account> newObjectsMap,map<id,Account> MapOldAccMap){
    //call update method
    updateEntitlementRecord(newObjectsMap,MapOldAccMap);

}


public void updateEntitlementRecord(Map<Id,Account> newObjectsMap, Map<Id,Account> MapOldAccMap){
    entList = new List<Entitlement> ();
    entitlementMap = new Map<Id,Entitlement>();

    entList = [Select Id,accountId,BusinessHoursId,account.Support_Time_Zone__c FROM Entitlement WHERE accountId IN:newObjectsMap.keySet()];
    // call Custom setting
    Business_Hours__c bhs = Business_Hours__c.getInstance('Business Hours Id');
    string Americas = bhs.AMER__c;
    string APAC = bhs.APAC__c;
    string Europe_and_Africa = bhs.EUR__c;
    string The_Global = bhs.Global__c;
    string The_Middle_East = bhs.ME__c;

    for(Entitlement ent : entList) {
        entitlementMap.put(ent.accountId,ent);
    }

    for(Id accountId : newObjectsMap.keySet())
    {

        if(newObjectsMap.get(accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c != MapOldAccMap.get(accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c){
            Entitlement ent = entitlementMap.get(accountId);

            if(newObjectsMap.get(ent.accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c == 'AMER'){

                ent.BusinessHoursId = Americas;

            } else if(newObjectsMap.get(ent.accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c == 'EUR'){

                ent.BusinessHoursId = Europe_and_Africa; //EUR                              
            }
            else if(newObjectsMap.get(ent.accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c == 'APAC'){

                ent.BusinessHoursId = APAC; //APAC             

            }
            else if(newObjectsMap.get(ent.accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c == 'ME'){

                ent.BusinessHoursId = The_Middle_East; //ME          

            }
            else if(newObjectsMap.get(ent.accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c == null){

                ent.BusinessHoursId = Americas; //None          

            }
            else if(newObjectsMap.get(ent.accountId).Support_Time_Zone__c == 'Global'){

                ent.BusinessHoursId = The_Global; //Global          

            } 
        }
    }



    if(entList.size() > 0)
        update entList;

}
}`
```

This is test class

```
  `@isTest (seeAllData=true)
   public class AccountEntitlementTriggerHandlerTest {

static testmethod void Testupdate(){
    Account ac = new Account(name ='TestCustomerAccount',Industry = 'Manufacturing');            
    insert ac;

    //retrieve Default Entitlement Process information
 Id entitlementProcessId = [SELECT Id FROM SlaProcess 
                       WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' AND Isactive = true
                       AND Name= 'Standard Support'].Id;

    Entitlement ent = new Entitlement( name= 'TestDefault', AccountId = ac.Id,SlaProcessId =entitlementProcessId);
    insert ent;

   Test.startTest();
    ac.Support_Time_Zone__c = 'AMER';
    update ent;
   Test.stopTest(); 

  }
  }`
```

what i am trying to do is when a field on account is getting update i am trying to update business hours field on entitlements.
I m not getting any errors in Test class but percentage covered is Zero. I am new to test classes. 
What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Check if your trigger class is getting covered or not???  From their you can get to know which method is failing ..and do system debug

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to unit testing, a good place to start would be [Trailheads: Get Started with Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro) .

> Testing is the key to successful long-term development and is a
> critical component of the development process
>
> - Calls to System.debug are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
> - Test methods and test classes are not counted as part of Apex code coverage. While only 75% of your Apex code must be covered by tests,
>   your focus shouldn't be on the percentage of code that is
>   covered.Instead, you should make sure that every use case of your
>   application is covered, including positive and negative cases, as well
>   as bulk and single records.
> - This should lead to 75% or more of your code being covered by unit tests.
> - Every trigger must have some test coverage.
> - All classes and triggers must compile successfully.

you might want to check other Apex Test Class questions on the forum  (there are plenty)

***What am I dong wrong?***

you should make sure that every use case of your application is covered, you dont seem to be covering any use cases.

[Debugging, Testing, and Deploying Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debug_test_deploy.htm)